# How to convert perl modules into deb packages?

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu, deb

My team is delivering a product that requires some perl modules, and since we deliver a full OS installer (Ubuntu 12.04) we want those modules as .deb packages. I've been able to build some other perl (like Algorithm::LUHN, Env::C, Linux::PID and Config::Properties) by following the instructions [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/78/Building_Debian_packages_of_Perl_modules), but having problems with Apache2::SizeLimit

Tried with Apache-SizeLimit-0.96 and Apache-SizeLimit-0.97... and all the methods described in the doc. Also tried in different OSs versions; Ubuntu 14.04.2, Ubuntu 12.04.5 (clean install), all the attempts ended with the same error:

```
test@test:~$ dh-make-perl --build --cpan Apache::SizeLimit
Going to read '/home/test/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 19 Mar 2015 02:17:02 GMT
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.61)
Checksum for /home/test/.cpan/sources/authors/id/P/PH/PHRED/Apache-SizeLimit-0.97.tar.gz ok
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/Changes
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/INSTALL
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/lib/
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/LICENSE
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/Makefile.PL
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/MANIFEST
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/MANIFEST.SKIP
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/META.json
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/META.yml
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/README
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/t/
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/t/apache/
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/t/apache2/
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/t/pod.t
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/t/response/
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/t/response/TestApache/
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/t/response/TestApache2/
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/t/response/TestApache2/basic.pm
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/t/response/TestApache2/check_n_requests2.pm
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/t/response/TestApache2/deprecated.pm
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/t/response/TestApache2/zzz_check_n_requests.pm
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/t/response/TestApache/basic.pm
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/t/response/TestApache/check_n_requests2.pm
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/t/response/TestApache/deprecated.pm
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/t/response/TestApache/zzz_check_n_requests.pm
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/t/apache2/all.t
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/t/apache/all.t
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/lib/Apache/
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/lib/Apache2/
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/lib/Apache2/SizeLimit.pm
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/lib/Apache/SizeLimit/
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/lib/Apache/SizeLimit.pm
Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/lib/Apache/SizeLimit/Core.pm
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)
======================================================================
Unpacked tarball already existed, directory renamed to /home/test/Apache-SizeLimit-0.97.13910
======================================================================
Using META.json
Found: Apache2-SizeLimit 0.97 (libapache2-sizelimit-perl arch=all)
cat: /etc/mailname: No such file or directory
No APT contents can be loaded.
Please install 'apt-file' package (at least version 2.5.0) and
run 'apt-file update' as root.
Dependencies not updated.
Using maintainer: test 
Found docs: README
cat: /etc/mailname: No such file or directory
Using rules: /usr/share/dh-make-perl/rules.dh7.tiny
cat: /etc/mailname: No such file or directory
make: Entering directory `/home/test/Apache-SizeLimit-0.97'
dh clean
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
   dh_clean
make: Leaving directory `/home/test/Apache-SizeLimit-0.97'
make: Entering directory `/home/test/Apache-SizeLimit-0.97'
dh build
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_configure
Can't find mod_perl installed
The error was: Can't locate mod_perl2.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at Makefile.PL line 147.
dh_auto_configure: perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=vendor returned exit code 2
make: *** [build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/home/test/Apache-SizeLimit-0.97'
Cannot create deb package: 'debian/rules build' failed.
```

Will appreciate any help on fixing it

Comment: I'd say the error message is pretty clear: you need to [install `mod_perl2`](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/install/install.html), or tell Perl where it's installed if you installed it outside of `@INC`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. As far as I understand mod_perl is installed alongside apache2... will check the link you shared

Comment: mod_perl is not part of the default Apache installation, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thank you, your comment helped a lot in getting this issue sorted on Alpine Linux image (after installing package `apache2-dev`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharing how it was solved. As @grant-mclean answered; I was missing a -dev package: the "apache2-dev" (apache2-threaded-dev).
With it, and skipping tests I was able to build the .deb package.

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts dh-make-perl libapache2-mod-perl2 libapache2-mod-perl2-dev apache2-threaded-dev
export DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS="$DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS nocheck"
dh-make-perl --build --cpan Apache::SizeLimit
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you're trying to build something on Debian and get a message about something being missing, you need to install a 'dev' package - one that contains things like header files that aren't needed by the runtime.

I'm just guessing, but in your case perhaps you need to install: `libapache2-mod-perl2-dev`

Comment: Perhaps that's true in general, but in this case, the OP is missing a Perl module, not C header files. `mod_perl2.pm` is provided by [libapache2-mod-perl2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/libapache2-mod-perl2/filelist).